# Get argument count of a PHP function with optional arguments

Tags: php

Can any one tell which function to use to determine the number of arguments passed within a function that has optional arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean [`func_num_args`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php)? That will count the *passed* arguments, but not those that are not passed and get the default value:

```
function foo($a, $b='bar') {
   echo func_num_args() . PHP_EOL;
}

foo(1);
foo(1,2);
foo(1,'bar');
```

prints

```
1
2
2
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/fLowg34Q)

Comment: I think he wants to test if a function `xyz($a, $b='')` was called like `xyz(1)` or `xyz(1, 'foo')`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Isn't that what `func_num_arg` is doing? Or I don't get your point...

Comment: Indeed. I thought func_num_args counts all arguments.. no matter if default or passed manually.